# Outlook JS Add-in - displayReplyFormAsync() with item attachment not working for shared mailbox

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

**What the add-in does:**
If the user clicks on a button shown in the taskpane, the `displayReplyFormAsync` function is called and the current mail shall be added to itself as an attachment:

```
Office.context.mailbox.item?.displayReplyFormAsync({
  htmlBody: globalThis.UIText.ForwardedSeeAttachment,
  attachments: [
    { type: "item", itemId: Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId, name: "original.msg" }
  ],
  options: { asyncContext: null }
});
```

The add-in is permitted to work in shared folder in the manifest.xml:

```
<Host ...>
    <DesktopFormFactor>
        <SupportsSharedFolders>true</SupportsSharedFolders>
```

**The issue**
If the item is in a shared mailbox, Outlook (Desktop on Windows) shows the following error message:

> There was an error attaching one or more of the attachments. You can close this response and try again in the app.

I get the `Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId` no matter if it is a shared mail item or not.

Do I have to treat shared mailboxes differently?

Comment: A bug has been opened for this in the Product Team's backlog. It is unknown when or if it will be addressed. For right now, it appears that displayReplyFormAsync can only add items who belong to the main Exchange Account and not the Shared Mailboxes.